# How can this association be set up?

Tags: php, cakephp, associations

I'm using the cakephp framework to develop an application and I'm running into some trouble understanding the associations between these models fully. Below you can see the four models along with their relative database fields.

```
User
 id

Profile
 id
 user_id

Post (A blog post on the users profile)
 id
 profile_id
 topic_id

Topic (A topic for a blog post)
 id
 name
```

Here are the associations as they currently stand:

```
User
 hasOne: Profile

Profile
 hasMany: Posts

Post
 belongsTo: Topic, Profile
```

Now my problem. I am unsure if you have to define associations like `User hasMany Posts` or if it's already assumed because `User hasOne Profile` and `Profile hasMany Posts`. My other problem is defining the relationship between a post and its topic.

- A profile can have unlimited posts
- A post must be associated with a profile
- A post can only have one topic
- The topic table contains a list of all topics
- A post does not NEED a topic

Given these criteria how should my associations look? All the research I've done on associations only shows simple examples.

I'm using CakePHP version 2.1.3

Thanks for any and all help and/or advice in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recursively find associations of associations, or even better, use Containable.

In the model (I recommend putting it in AppModel, since I find myself using Containable for everything):

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    ...
}
```

Then when you call read (or find, or paginate) for User, most likely in your controller, do this:

```
$this->User->contain(array(
    'Profile' => array(
        'Post'
    )
));
$data = $this->User->read();
$set('user',$data);
```

If you set that data to your view, you can then access the id of one of the posts from `$user['Profile']['Post'][0]['id']`.

Now for your next question, you can have conditional associations.

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Topic' => array(
        'className' => 'Topic',
        'conditions' => 'Post.topic_id IS NOT NULL'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and extra information, I've accepted this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think everything looks fine

Your assumption is correct you dont have to define the User / Post relationship. Users dont have many Posts, Profiles do. You could store the user_id on the Post rather than profile_id to make thing a bit more intuitive but thats up to you.

Topic hasMany Post and you are done. The topic/post conditions you describe can be controlled via the forms and before saves on the model. For example 'A post must be associated with a profile', well at the point you save the post you add in the profile_id based on session info of the logged in user.

Comment: I've voted your answer up since you were able to answer one of my questions, however the other answer was more informative and included examples so I've given them the acceptance. Thanks a lot for the help.